# Machine Learning Libraries For Android

Tags: android, machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, text-mining

I am trying build a small text mining tool for my android app. I am checking for a machine learning library that will allow me to cluster, classify etc.

Are there any machine learning libraries for android? I came across tensorflow but I need a bit more access to common ML functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try these ports of weka for android (they do not use the latest weka version, but it may be sufficient for your needs):

https://github.com/rjmarsan/Weka-for-Android

https://github.com/andrecamara/weka-android

Comment: thanks for sharing. I will keep the question open to see whether I get more suggestions. weka looks very promising.

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow does give you access to a huge number of machine learning functions.
Using `tf.contrib.learn` you don't even have to write the code for an optimizer.

You can use the optimizers that are already included in the library.
You only need to preprocess your data in a proper fashion and then feed it to the neural network.

Here's a link to an example provided by TensorFlow for Android:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android

Comment: I don't find anything related to text processing in that example. I see Computer Vision related examples. Are there other examples?

Regarding: tf.contrib.learn, I think it's for DeepLearning.

Comment: Deep learning is a part of machine learning so I don't think that's a problem. And if you want another example check this out:

https://github.com/miyosuda/TensorFlowAndroidMNIST

Comment: Once again you are pointing an example for text recognition based on DeepLearning with tensorflow. What if i need to cluster(k-means, gmm), classify (random forest, svm), topic model(lda, lsa)? All I am looking for is a basic utility library for machine learning that i need not port or rewrite. Something like dlib, scikit-learn or torch for android.